# How to handle type and input into WYSWYG editor such as tinymce when testing using selenium RC?

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, phpunit, rc

is there any solution to this problem

i use :

> $this->type('contentform', 'i need to print this and go on with my testing');

but after i do submit it failed while when i do it manually it work. i'm using this code for submit:

> $this->click("publish");

i test my app via selenium RC + phpunit
ps: it work in selenium IDE but failed in selenium RC. i wonder why ?

Comment: Does it work with the selenium IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm able to do this using typeKeys

now, rather then use 'type', i use 'typeKeys'. so i will type texts into WYSWYG Editor such as TinyMCE such as :

```
$this->typeKeys('contentform', 'i need to print this and go on with my testing');
```